# Android App Crashes after passing data

Tags: java, android

I come here often to look for references and assistance in order to complete my assignments for school. I am a beginner in Java programming along with Eclipse and Android. However I have program in C++, PL/SQL and HTML so I have some understand of basic programming rules. Up to this point the program runs however when I create the intent and pass data to calculate the GPA, it crashes. I look for it literally hours and I can't seem to find the problem. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.gpacalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonGoback;
    private double gpa=0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        Bundle secondBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        buttonGoback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonReturn);
        buttonGoback.setOnClickListener(this);

        int idGrades[] = getLetterIds();

        String grade;
        int hour;

        String[] grades = new String[2];
        int[] hours = new int[2];

         for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)
            {

                grade = secondBundle.getString("grade_"+i);
                grades[i]=grade;

                hour =  secondBundle.getInt("hourse_"+i,3);
                hours[i] =hour;

            }

         gpa = calculateGPA(grades, hours);

    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        TextView results = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_output);
        String temp = String.valueOf(gpa);
        results.setText(temp);

    }

    double calculateGPA(String[] grades,int[] hours)
    {
        double gpa=0.0d;
        int totalHours=0;
        for (int i=0; i < grades.length; i++)
        {
            totalHours += hours[i];

            if(grades[i].toUpperCase().equals("A"))
                gpa += 4.0 * hours[i];
            if(grades[i].toUpperCase().equals("B"))
                gpa += 3.0 * hours[i];
            if(grades[i].toUpperCase().equals("C"))
                gpa += 2.0 * hours[i];
            if(grades[i].toUpperCase().equals("D"))
                gpa += 1.0 * hours[i];
            if(grades[i].toUpperCase().equals("D"))
                gpa += 0.0 * hours[i]; //redundant!

        }
        gpa = gpa /totalHours;

        return gpa;
    }

    public int[] getLetterIds() 
    {

        int[] LetterIds = new int[10];

        LetterIds[0] = R.id.edittext_course1; 
        LetterIds[1] = R.id.edittext_course2; 
        LetterIds[2] = R.id.edittext_course3;
        LetterIds[3] = R.id.edittext_course4;
        LetterIds[4] = R.id.edittext_course5;
        LetterIds[5] = R.id.edittext_course6;
        LetterIds[6] = R.id.edittext_course7;
        LetterIds[7] = R.id.edittext_course8;
        LetterIds[8] = R.id.edittext_course9;
        LetterIds[9] = R.id.edittext_course10;

        return LetterIds;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the first activity:

```
package com.example.gpacalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonStart;
    private int GPA_CODE=1001;

    public int[] getLetterIds() {

        int[] LetterIds = new int[10];

        LetterIds[0] = R.id.edittext_course1; 
        LetterIds[1] = R.id.edittext_course2; 
        LetterIds[2] = R.id.edittext_course3;
        LetterIds[3] = R.id.edittext_course4;
        LetterIds[4] = R.id.edittext_course5;
        LetterIds[5] = R.id.edittext_course6;
        LetterIds[6] = R.id.edittext_course7;
        LetterIds[7] = R.id.edittext_course8;
        LetterIds[8] = R.id.edittext_course9;
        LetterIds[9] = R.id.edittext_course10;

        return LetterIds;
    }

    public int[] getHoursIds() {

        int[] HoursIds = new int[10];

        HoursIds[0] = R.id.edittext_hrs1;
        HoursIds[1] = R.id.edittext_hrs2; 
        HoursIds[2] = R.id.edittext_hrs3;
        HoursIds[3] = R.id.edittext_hrs4;
        HoursIds[4] = R.id.edittext_hrs5;
        HoursIds[5] = R.id.edittext_hrs6;
        HoursIds[6] = R.id.edittext_hrs7;
        HoursIds[7] = R.id.edittext_hrs8;
        HoursIds[8] = R.id.edittext_hrs9;
        HoursIds[9] = R.id.edittext_hrs10;

        return HoursIds;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstart);
        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Bundle firstBundle = new Bundle();

        int letterarray[]= getLetterIds();
        int hourarray[]= getHoursIds();

        String gradestr;
        int hours;

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
        {
            gradestr = ((EditText) findViewById(letterarray[i])).getText().toString();
            hours = Integer.parseInt(((EditText) findViewById(hourarray[i]))
                    .getText().toString());
            firstBundle.putString("grade_" + i, gradestr);
            firstBundle.putInt("hours_" + i, hours);

        }

        Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        firstIntent.putExtras(firstBundle);

        startActivity(firstIntent);

    }


}
```

And the error log:

```
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gpacalculator/com.example.gpacalculator.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at com.example.gpacalculator.SecondActivity.calculateGPA(SecondActivity.java:66)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at com.example.gpacalculator.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:46)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-26 17:22:38.350: E/AndroidRuntime(29097):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The stacktrace from the crash would be **awesome** right about now

Comment: Post your logs, also what intent? All I see is method call to calculate gpa. Post your logs please.

Comment: This for-loop looks odd `for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
for (int i=0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        grade = secondBundle.getString("grade_"+i);
        grades[i]=grade;

        hour =  secondBundle.getInt("hourse_"+i,3);
        hours[i] =hour;

    }
```

grade[1] is not initialized,

At line 66, grades[1] is null.

Try changing line 35 to for (int i=0; i < grades.length; i++)